# How to calculate expected number of turns using DP in O(n)?

Tags: c++, math, dynamic-programming, probability

A single-player board game. The board is made up of a row of n cells numbered 1 to n from left to
right. Cell ‘j' contains a positive integer cj.
The rules are like this:

1. You start on the leftmost cell.
2. On each turn, you roll a fair 6-sided die with A as the outcome number. You
   move forward A × cj cells, where j is the index of the cell that you are standing
   on.
3. You win once you exit the board i.e., you win when your index j > n.

For instance, consider the board of size n=10
To begin with, you are at the first cell having the value c1 = 2. In the first turn, you roll a dice
and obtain a value 1, so you move forward 2 cells. Then on the next roll you roll a 5 on cell 3
(with c3 = 4), so you move forward 20 cells makes you exit the board. You win!! You took 2
turns to win.

How to calculate the expected number of turns needed to win using dynamic programming algorithm that runs in time (n) for the above game?

Comment: why dynamic programming? Its just a matter of doing the maths to get the solution in O(1)

Comment: It cannot be O(1) as the result depends on the content of the array. DP would work. But stackoverflow is not about solving your homework for you, Rushil. It's about helping unstuck you if you have a specific problem doing something specific while writing your solution.

Comment: @spectras oh right, I misread that the numbers are always 1,2,3,....n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence relation you're looking for is:

```
E[j] = 0 (if j > n)
E[j] = 1 + 1/6 * sum_k(E[j + k * c_j]) (otherwise, for k \in 1..6)
```

Comment: can you clarify what sum_k is doing ?

Comment: sum of evaluating the expression with k set to 1, 2, ..., 6.

Answer (score 2):

For each cell, calculate how many turns to win on average.

For cell[k] with k>=n, this is 0.

For other cells with k<n, it 1 plus the average of turns to win at cell[1..6*c_k].

Cache results and don't recalculate them.

Return turns to win from cell 0.

Yes, this is seemingly nothing non-obvious.  Dynamic programming is seeming to do nothing non-obvious, with an appropriately bounded cache in the middle of the naive algorithm.

The trick is arranging the problem to have a cache with good bounds that makes a naive algorithm collapse into not doing much work.